# Order covariates with interaction in stargazer

Tags: r, model, linear-regression, stargazer

I am unable to order my regression output in `stargazer`.  I have a regression model with an interaction term:

```
reg <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1*x2 + x3..., data = data1)
```

I tried several things with stargazer:

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(reg, type ="html", out = "file.html", order = c("x1*x2", "x2"...))
```

and

```
stargazer(reg, type ="html", out = "file.html", order = c("^x1*x2$", "^x2$"...))
```

I also tried:

```
vars.order <- c("x1*x2", "x2"...)
```

and put it in stargazer

```
stargazer(reg, type ="html", out = "file.html", order = paste0("^" , vars.order, "$"),..)
```

but my variables do not follow the order I am trying to assign them to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open for other packages, I use the [`texreg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/index.html) package and do this in no time. *Example:*

```
library(texreg)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp + cyl*drat, mtcars)
screenreg(fit, reorder.coef=c(5, 1:4))
# ====================
#              Model 1
# --------------------
# cyl:drat      -0.79 
#               (0.80)
# (Intercept)    5.41 
#              (19.14)
# hp            -0.02 
#               (0.02)
# cyl            1.32 
#               (2.82)
# drat           7.50 
#               (4.97)
# --------------------
# R^2            0.78 
# Adj. R^2       0.74 
# Num. obs.     32    
# RMSE           3.05 
# ====================
# *** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Use `texreg::screenreg` for console,  `texreg::htmlreg` for HTML,  and `texreg::texreg` for LaTeX.